# Angular js file upload issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Below is my controller code and the custom directive to upload file:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, elemesnt, attrs) {
              element.bind('change', function(){
              $parse(attrs.fileModel).assign(scope,element[0].files)
                 scope.$apply();
              });
           }
        };
}])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
       $scope.uploadFile=function(){
       var fd=new FormData();
        console.log($scope.files);
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
        fd.append('file',file);
        });
       $http.post('http://192.168.1.161/www/ci_practice/assets/',fd,
           {
               transformRequest: angular.identity,
               headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}                     
            }).success(function(d)
                {
                    console.log(d);
                })         
       }
}]);
```

I am not able to upload a image the the assets folder.
Please help me out.

Comment: You might not want to have the IP address you're using publicly visible to everyone.

Comment: It would be helpful if you go through the [Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and frame your question in a better way to reflect the problem. You can refer [this helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var f = $scope.files,
        r = new FileReader();
        r.onloadend = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        //send your binary data via $http
       }

    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
```

Comment: Can we save the uploaded file into folder..can u help me with the code as i am new learner in angular js.

Comment: do you mean you want to upload the file into you a folder then you need to do in the backend - best practise i mean. whats uur backend

Comment: i use php mysql